# How to send a different data type in c #

Tags: c#

I am using httpclient and I want to send the data I specified in the picture over the console, but I do not know how to do it.

[image]

My codes:

```
StringContent ark = new StringContent("{\"query\":\"query search($region: String!, $startsWith: String!, $pageSize: Int, $currentPage: Int, $preferredGameId: String!) { findProfiles(region: $region, nameBeginsWith: $startsWith, pageSize: $pageSize, page: $currentPage) { totalCount nodes { id avatar(preferredGameId: $preferredGameId) { gameId face full } } } }\",\"variables\":\"{\"region\":\"TR\",\"startsWith\":\"Mertiny\",\"pageSize\":60,\"currentPage\":1,\"preferredGameId\":\"j68d\"}\",\"operationName\":\"\"}",
                                        Encoding.UTF8,
                                        "application/json");

var idconvert = await client.PostAsync("https://eu.mspapis.com/edgerelationships/graphql/graphql", ark);
```

the data I have to send

```
{
    "query": "query search($region: String!, $startsWith: String!, $pageSize: Int, $currentPage: Int, $preferredGameId: String!) { findProfiles(region: $region, nameBeginsWith: $startsWith, pageSize: $pageSize, page: $currentPage) { totalCount nodes { id avatar(preferredGameId: $preferredGameId) { gameId face full } } } }",
    "variables": "{\"region\":\"TR\",\"startsWith\":\"meryem123Neroo\",\"pageSize\":60,\"currentPage\":1,\"preferredGameId\":\"j68d\"}",
    "operationName": ""
}
```

Comment: Hi @mert and welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you please provide more details on what error do you get when you run that code?

Comment: Failed to parse data (org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at 337 [character 338 line1]}

Comment: Are you sure `variables` is supposed to be a string and not a json object?

Comment: Your string content is malformed, the variables section is wrong

Comment: But this is GraphQL, so you are far better off using a proper client like https://www.nuget.org/packages/GraphQL.Client/

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes, the variables section should be a string that contains a JSON object

Comment: @Mert try using this for your string content: `var content = "{\"query\":\"query search($region: String!, $startsWith: String!, $pageSize: Int, $currentPage: Int, $preferredGameId: String!) { findProfiles(region: $region, nameBeginsWith: $startsWith, pageSize: $pageSize, page: $currentPage) { totalCount nodes { id avatar(preferredGameId: $preferredGameId) { gameId face full } } } }\",\"variables\":\"{\\\"region\\\":\\\"TR\\\",\\\"startsWith\\\":\\\"Mertiny\\\",\\\"pageSize\\\":60,\\\"currentPage\\\":1,\\\"preferredGameId\\\":\\\"j68d\\\"}\",\"operationName\":\"\"}";`